# SQL Command that Returns Month/Year col and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying this for sometime, and appear to have hit a roadblock.

I want to group and count Hours by month.

My SQL Table:

| id | Date | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1645176391 | 2.1 |
| 1 | 1645435591 | 1.6 |
| 1 | 1642152391 | 1.4 |
| 1 | 1647246391 | 1.7 |
| 2 | 1647246391 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 1647591991 | 0.4 |

My current attempt:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(Date, '%m-%Y') AS prod_month, COUNT(Hours)
            FROM my_table
            WHERE Date > [last 365 days in unix timestamp]
            AND id = 1
            GROUP BY
            prod_month;"
```

So, ideally the result would return something like:

| prod_month | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| 02-2022 | 3.7 |
| 01-2022 | 1.4 |
| 03-2022 | 2.1 |

Comment: What's your problem? If you have an error publish it in full. PS count(hours) ? Is that a typo?

Comment: No error… just returns 0 no matter what I try. I know the data is there, so I guess I’m posting here as a sanity check.

Comment: >  [last 365 days in unix timestamp] has to produce an error please publish actual code. Also last 365 dates from what date in table now() or something else?

Comment: The code I had there was: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 year));
1244433347

Comment: Just reviewed the db and it's an INT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made three tweaks to your query:

- adopted `SUM` instead of `COUNT`, to sum up hours
- added `ROUND` to round your sum to two numbers
- used [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to transform current date in unixtime and make comparison in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(Date_, '%m-%Y') AS prod_month, 
       ROUND(SUM(Hours),2)           AS Hours 
FROM my_table
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) < Date_
  AND id = 1
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(Date_, '%m-%Y')
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bxjty3UpC8XoBkNpSn3vZG/0).